# using mysql what will be the fastest way to join tables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, join

i have two tables "User" And "UsersSettings" .

and i want to select User's where the users settings is something 
what query will be more fast ?

```
SELECT u.*, us.someSettings FROM User u,UserSettings us 
WHERE u.id = us.user_id 
AND us.somesettings = somevalue 
AND u.someProperty = someOtherValue
AND u.someProperty1 = someOtherValue1
AND u.someProperty2 = someOtherValue2
AND u.someProperty3 = someOtherValue3
AND u.someProperty4 = someOtherValue4
AND us.someUSProperty  = someUSvalue
```

OR

```
SELECT u.*, us.someSettings FROM User u
LEFT JOIN UserSettings us ON us.user_id = u.id
WHERE us.somesettings = somevalue 
AND u.someProperty = someOtherValue
AND u.someProperty1 = someOtherValue1
AND u.someProperty2 = someOtherValue2
AND u.someProperty3 = someOtherValue3
AND u.someProperty4 = someOtherValue4
AND us.someUSProperty  = someUSvalue
```

can you help me please
thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query is an inner join:

```
SELECT u.*, us.someSettings
FROM User u INNER JOIN
     UserSettings us
     ON us.user_id = u.id
WHERE us.somesettings = somevalue 
AND u.someProperty = someOtherValue
AND u.someProperty1 = someOtherValue1
AND u.someProperty2 = someOtherValue2
AND u.someProperty3 = someOtherValue3
AND u.someProperty4 = someOtherValue4
AND us.someUSProperty  = someUSvalue;
```

You have a filtering condition on `UserSetting`s, so the outer join is turned to an inner join anyway.  You should avoid implicit `join` syntax and put the join conditions explicitly in an `on` clause.  This is for readability and maintainability.  Both versions should have the same performance.